# Как перевести на русский "parametricity"?

Tags: заимствования, терминология, математика

[Parametricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity).

Из матетатики, что-то типа свойства общности функторов, не зависящих от того над каким множеством работают их параметры-функции.

Google Translate молчит. Wiktionary молчит. В поиске особо не находится.

Как тогда по-русски говорить "parametricity"? "Параметричность"? Кто-нибудь поймёт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметрический --прилагательное, параметричность--соответственно, существительное.

http://ru.enc.tfode.com/

Здесь статья с разделом "параметричность".

Comment: Ещё нашёл: http://newstar.rinet.ru/~goga/tapl/tapl029.html#toc135